# Probability distribution of max of a set of random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{n}$ be $n$ random variables.

It's known that,
$P(X_{i} > t) \le f(t)$, $\forall i=1,2,\ldots,n$ where $f(t)$ is a function of $t$ and is the same across all $i$.

Let $X^{*}=\max\{X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{n}\}$.

Can I claim the following?
$P(X^{*} > t) \le f(t)$

Comment: You have $X^{*}>t$ if and only if at least _one_ of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ exceeds $t$.  If the probability that any one of those events happens is $1/100$ does that mean the probability that _at least_ one of them happens (when, say, $n=1000$) is no bigger than $1/100$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If the $X_i$'s are independent, you can with Michael Hardy's comment get a bound of
$$ \mathbb{P}\{X^\ast > t\} \leq 1-(1-f(t))^n.$$
As a sanity check: $f(t)=1$ (vacuous bound) implies the RHS is also 1 (vacuous). And $f(t)=0$ ($X_i$ is a.s. $\leq t$ for all $i$) indeed implies the RHS is $0$ ($X^\ast$ is a.s. $\leq t$).

Answer (score 1):

No, of course not. Consider Uniform[0,1] random variables, and $f(t) = 1-t$. It's easy to see $P(\max\{X_1,...,X_n\} > t) = 1 - t^n$, and so the statement fails.

If you want to reverse the inequality, $P(X_{i} > t) \ge f(t)$, then the reverse statement should be true.